# CCAN JSON Serialization in C

Tags: c, json, file

I'm using [JSON](http://ccodearchive.net/info/json.html) library. It's quite light and easy to understand, but I have one problem with json_decode. I'm reading data(JSON) from file:

```
FILE *instream = fopen("/tmp/file.dat", "r");
char ch;
int count = 0;
do {
    ch = getc(instream);
    inbuffer[count] = ch;
count++;
} while (!feof(instream) && ch != '\0');
```

My file look like below, so inbuffer has the same text

```
[
        {
                "MBV": 0,
                "CRRC": 0,
                "LFrei": 0
        }                
]
```

I try to decode it to have JsonNode variable

```
static char *chomp(char *s) //function taken from CCAN JSON example
{
    char *e;
    if (s == NULL || *s == 0)
        return s;

    e = strchr(s, 0);
    if (e[-1] == '\n')
        *--e = 0;
    return s;
}

const char *s = chomp(inbuffer);
JsonNode *jin = json_decode(s);
printf("JSON: %s\n", jin);
```

After I run my program I get

```
JSON: (null)
```

Can somebody tell me why json_decode function doesn't want to read JSON formatted file even if the file created using this library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the JSON library you ar using but I suspect the error occurs because `inbuffer` is not correctly NUL terminated. On end of file, `getc()` returns EOF (-1) what you copy into `inbuffer` before `feof()` returns TRUE. I would do:

```
while( (ch = getc( instream )) != EOF ) {
   inbuffer[count] = ch;
   count++;
}
inbuffer[count] = '\0';
```

or just use `fread()`:

```
count = fread( inbuffer, 1, sizeof( inbuffer ) - 1, stream );
inbuffer[count] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 2):

This code prints all the key-value pairs found in the first object of the array (your example shows an array containing only one object, which in turn contains three key-value items):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ccan/json/json.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fd;
    long filesize;
    char *buffer;
    JsonNode *jin, *node;

    if ((fd = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
    filesize = ftell(fd);
    rewind(fd);

    buffer = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * filesize+1);

    if (fread(buffer, sizeof(char), filesize, fd) != filesize) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading file\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    buffer[filesize] = '\0';

    jin = json_decode(buffer);
    json_foreach(node, jin->children.head)
        printf("%s: %g\n", node->key, node->number_);

    free(buffer);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Take into account that the traversal I just did heavily depends on the structure of the JSON you're trying to parse. If it fits your needs, fine, but maybe you'll need to find a more general solution. Take a look at the `json.h` header file included with the library to understand how the JSON structure is stored in memory once decoded from the file.

Also, in my personal experience, I've found the [JSON-C](https://github.com/json-c/json-c/wiki) library much easier to use than this one.